# WebFlux which code style is most preferable

Tags: spring-webflux

I have a question about the code style for webflux, there are two options for writing code, which option is the most correct?
Option one:

```
return Mono.create(emitter -> {
            try{
                var buffImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                Graphics2D g2d = buffImg.createGraphics();
                g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);

                myLineDAO.getMyLineByCoordinatePlane(maxLat, maxLon, minLat, minLon)
                        .subscribe(
                                value -> {
                                    var coordinates = value.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                                    var color = getColor(value.getRgbParameter());
                                    g2d.setColor(color);

                                    int x1 = -1;
                                    int y1 = -1;
                                    int x2 = 0;
                                    int y2 = 0;

                                    for(Coordinate coordinate : coordinates){
                                        if(x1 == -1 && y1 == -1){
                                            x1 = convertToPixelWeightPoint(coordinate.getX(), minLon, stepLon, stepX);
                                            y1 = convertToPixelHeightPoint(coordinate.getY(), minLat, stepLat, stepY);
                                        }else{
                                            x2 = convertToPixelWeightPoint(coordinate.getX(), minLon, stepLon, stepX);
                                            y2 = convertToPixelHeightPoint(coordinate.getY(), minLat, stepLat, stepY);

                                            g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

                                            x1 = x2;
                                            y1 = y2;
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                error -> {
                                    logger.error("Exception when getting sequence element: {}", error.getMessage());
                                    error.printStackTrace();
                                },
                                () -> {
                                    try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                                        ImageIO.write(buffImg, IMAGE_FORMAT, baos);
                                        byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                                        logger.info("Byte array create");
                                        emitter.success(bytes);

                                    }catch (Exception e){
                                        logger.error("Exception in the image to byte array conversion block: {}", e.getMessage());
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        emitter.success(getPictureErrorHasOccurred());
                                    }
                                }
                        );


            }catch (Exception e){
                logger.error("Exception by rendering: {}", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                emitter.error(e);
            }
        });
```

Option two:

```
return myLineDAO.getMyLineByCoordinatePlane(maxLat, maxLon, minLat, minLon)
                .collectList()
                .map(myLineList -> {
                    var buffImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

                    Graphics2D g2d = buffImg.createGraphics();
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                    
                    for(MyLine myLine : myLineList){
                        var coordinates = myLine.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
                        var color = getColor(myLine.getRgbParameter());
                        g2d.setColor(color);

                        int x1 = -1;
                        int y1 = -1;
                        int x2 = 0;
                        int y2 = 0;

                        for(Coordinate coordinate : coordinates){
                            if(x1 == -1 && y1 == -1){
                                x1 = convertToPixelWeightPoint(coordinate.getX(), minLon, stepLon, stepX);
                                y1 = convertToPixelHeightPoint(coordinate.getY(), minLat, stepLat, stepY);
                            }else{
                                x2 = convertToPixelWeightPoint(coordinate.getX(), minLon, stepLon, stepX);
                                y2 = convertToPixelHeightPoint(coordinate.getY(), minLat, stepLat, stepY);

                                g2d.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

                                x1 = x2;
                                y1 = y2;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[1];
                    try(ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
                        ImageIO.write(buffImg, IMAGE_FORMAT, baos);
                        bytes = baos.toByteArray();
                        logger.info("Byte array create");
                    }catch (Exception e){
                        logger.error("Exception in the image to byte array conversion block: {}", e.getMessage());
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return bytes;
                });
```

The getMyLineByCoordinatePlane(...) method returns the set included in the area specified by the minimum and maximum coordinates. The entity contains a field of type Geometry (postgis) which is a set of coordinates (line). This has nothing to do with the current issue, just to make it clearer what is happening.

Blocking calls cannot be used in reactive programming. But purely theoretically, in any case, you will have to wait until all entities are received from the database. So why not subscribe to flux and process everything as it comes in?